# How to disable all click actions for context menu abort?

Tags: javascript

We have custom context menus that replace the browser menus on right click. We would like to be able to abort (hide) the context menu in the same way that the default context menu is hidden by the browser- a click anywhere outside the menu that *does not register as a click*. The solution should apply to both bound events and default browser actions, but not impede the ability for other events, ie. `hover` from firing.

**An example**:

In firefox, right click on this page to open the context menu. Hover over the

```
Questions-Tags-Users-Badges-Unanswered
```

at the top of this page. Even though the context menu is open, highlighting still occurs. Now, click on a text area on this page, like the search box at the top. The context menu will hide, but your cursor will not focus the text box (unless you click it again with the menu closed).

How can we emulate this behaviour in JavaScript?

**Rejected options we've considered**:

1. Use a transparent div over the whole page. Problem: This can capture clicks anywhere, but breaks hover events and hover css.
2. Check for a context-menu-open variable in each click handler, and assign handlers to all links, and input elements to detect the context menu open state, which closes the context menu, unset the open state and prevents the handlers default. Problem: Very sloppy code and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: just reporting that on my computer (firefox on windows), clicking with the context menu open does focus the text box

Comment: Using Firefox 37 on Ubuntu, the first click does not focus but only closes the context menu, as described.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a variation of rejected option #2, where you have a single event listener on the document.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (contextMenuOpen) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

For more information about that `true`, look up `useCapture` and [event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: One minor problem: the context menu event fires, then a click event fires afterwards. This causes the menu to open and then immediately close.

Comment: +1 for event capture. There were a few kinks to work out, namely dealing with the menu auto-closing and text areas being focusable because the focus event fired first.

Answer (score 0):

`Guest` was on the right track with event capture, but the solution had a few glitches. This is a more robust solution that solves the following problems:

1. Don't immediately close the menu in the right click event that fires right after context menu.
2. Don't let text fields get focused when the context menu is open- the focus event fires first and is not caught by a capture click event. We need to setup a capture handler on focus too.
3. Deal with the problems created by having a focus and click handler, which both fire.

To do this, you need two capture event handlers:

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(e){eDocumentFocusCapture(e)}, true);
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){eDocumentClickCapture(e)}, true);

// If the context menu is open, ignore the focus event.
eDocumentFocusCapture = function(e){
   if(RowContextMenuIsOpen){
      console.log('focus event sees the menu open: cancel focus, but leave menu be. Click will take care of closing it.');
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.blur(); // tell the clicked element it is not focused, otherwise you can't focus it until you click elsewhere first!
   }
}


eDocumentClickCapture = function(e){   

   // A right click fires immediatly after context menu is fired,
   // we prevent the menu from closing immediately by skipping one right click event
   if(RowContextMenuWasJustOpened===true && e.button===2){
      console.log('right click self bypass');
      RowContextMenuWasJustOpened=false;
      return;
   }

   if(this.protected.RowContextMenuIsOpen){
      console.log('click event sees menu open, I will close it.');
      this.HideRowContextMenu();      
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();      
   }
}
```